# SSIS, Foreach Loop, Event Handler when it writes 0 records due to file containing zero records

Tags: ssis, event-handling

I have a foreach loop container in my SSIS package.  the Data Flow task imports xls files from a certain directory.  If the xls file contains no data, the package shows in the log that it wrote 0 records. This is fine; however, I would like to envoke an event handler that will notify the user (email) or my user interface will pop up a message...that no records were processed. 
Is this possible?  If so, I wasn't sure what Event Handler to choose and how to configure properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an integer variable.
2. Place a rowcount task between the source and destination of the dataflow, and map the step to the variable.
3. Create an email task and connect the dataflow task to it with a
   "Success" constraint and an expression evaluation.
4. Insert the following value into the expression: " == 0".
5. This will send an email only when the dataflow results in zero
   records.